# How can I get a class parameter from a function of class via decorator class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, python-decorators

The problem:
I want to get an attribute of class via decorator which is a class but I can not.
The question is how can?

```
class DecoratorClass:

    def __call__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs) -> Callable:
        try:
            # do something with the TestClass value
            return fn
        finally:
            pass


class TestClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 1

    @DecoratorClass()
    def bar(self):
        return 1
```

How can I reach the the TestClass's value attr via DecoratorClass?

Comment: Related: [Access self from decorator](//stackoverflow.com/q/7590682)

Comment: Since the class and especially its `value` attribute doesn't exist at the point the decorator is executed: you can't. You can only do so in the callable itself, i.e. when `bar()` is being called.

Comment: @deceze that is interesting, I found solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution :)

```
class Decoratorclass:

    def __call__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs) -> Callable:

        def decorated(instance):
            try:
                # do something with the TestClass value
                print(instance.value)
                return fn(instance)
            finally:
                pass
        return decorated

class TestClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 1

    @Decoratorclass()
    def bar(self):
        return 1
```